# netbeans platform change orientation for arabic support

Tags: java, netbeans-platform

I am  working on Netbeans platform, and I want to support Arabic language, so all components should be right to left. My question is how to make all components orientation is RTL in  Netbeans platform, and how to make  Netbeans platform is language switcher (English, Arabic).
Thanks .

Comment: https://blogs.oracle.com/geertjan/entry/netbeans_platform_7_3_in

Comment: https://blogs.oracle.com/geertjan/entry/tips_for_arabic_java_desktop

Answer (score 0):

you could use it if you have components inside panels inside contentPane

```
        Component[] component = contentPane.getComponents();
    for(int i=0; i<component.length; i++){
        component[i].applyComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);
        Component[] cp = ((Container) component[i]).getComponents();
        for(int j=0; j<cp.length; j++){
            try{
                ((Component) ((JComboBox) cp[j]).getRenderer()).applyComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);
            }catch(Exception e){
                continue;

            }
        }
    }
```